# No error indicated for failed operation in Perl DBI module

Tags: mysql, windows, perl, dbi, strawberry-perl

I'm executing a script similar to the following and when there is a failed operation, the `execute` function returns an undefined value, so I can detect that it failed, so that's good. However, I find that `err()` and `errstr` don't return anything. I was expecting to get an error code and an error message, respectively. What I am doing wrong? Thanks for any info.

```
use DBI;
$db="foobar";
$host="localhost";
$user="root";
$password="mypassword";

my $dbh = DBI->connect("DBI:mysql:database=$db:host=$host",
    $user, $password) or die "Oops: $DBI::errstr\n";

my $sth = $dbh->prepare("invalid sql");
my $returnval = $sth->execute();
my $errcode = $sth->err();
my $errstring = $sth->errstr;
print "returnval=$returnval, errcode=$errcode, errstring=$errstring\n";
```

Output:

```
returnval=, errcode=, errstring=
```

I am working with Strawberry Perl (32-bit) on a 64-bit Windows 7 system. (I am working with 32-bit version because of another module I am using won't work with the 64-bit version.) `perl.exe --version` says: "This is perl 5, version 16, subversion 3 (v5.16.3) built for MSWin32-x86-multi-thread"

Comment: I have a recollection that DBD::mysql was broken a while back wrt to setting error messages. Check the change log and may be upgrade to a newer version.

Comment: @bohica I guess you're right. I found this bug report [1]. Looks like it isn't fixed yet (bug report is open and I ran into the same problem in the newest version). [1] https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=71555

Comment: aha, the same Robert Dodier that mailed the dbi-user/dbi-dev mailing list. I have offered my services so we'll wait and see what comes of your posting there.

Comment: Have you found anything ? I have the same problem with strawberry 5.14

Comment: @Sly the bug was fixed in a recent version and I got an updated version and found that the error message stuff now works as expected. I don't remember if it has been released in a package yet, or if I got the fixed version from their source code repository or something like that.

Comment: I've just downloaded Strawberry Perl 5.18.1.1 (32bit) and it has the exact same problem.

Comment: @Sly My email indicates that DBD-mysql-4.024 is the fixed version. I don't know if it is included in that version of Strawberry Perl. You might have to look at the change log for DBD-mysql.

Answer (score 0):

DBI->connect("DBI:mysql:database=$db:host=$host",
    $user, $password) or die "Oops: $DBI::errstr\n";

it should be like, try this it may work

DBI->connect("DBI:mysql:$db:$host:$portNumber",
    $user, $password) or die "Oops: $DBI::errstr\n";

I have used ActivePerl, we need to pass the mysql port number by default it will be 3306.

DBI->connect("DBI:mysql:$db:$host:3306",
    $user, $password) or die "Oops:errstr $! \n";

Answer (score 0):

`err` and `errstr` are methods of the `DBI` module, not the statement handles. You should say

```
my $errcode = $dbh->err();
my $errstring = $dbh->errstr;  # or  DBI->errstr  or  $DBI::errstr
```

Comment: Thanks for responding. Tried all those, same result every time (errcode and errstring are empty).

Comment: mob, err and errstr are methods common to all handles. In fact, the internals of DBI show there is only one internal err and errstr value that all handles use.